# How do I get the server name with aws ec2 describe-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I'm able to get the instance id, instance type, and public ip address into a table format. But I'm unable to parse the Tags Name. We plug in names for all of our servers to make them easier to identify.

Here's an example of what I've come up with so far

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress]' --output table

------------------------------------------------
|               DescribeInstances              |
+------------+-------------+-------------------+
|  i-64629700|  m1.small   |  54.227.243.165   |
|  i-2d300249|  m3.xlarge  |  23.23.166.230    |
|  i-7422c909|  m1.small   |  23.21.105.175    |
|  i-08c76e24|  m3.xlarge  |  54.235.253.163   |
|  i-99a20a72|  m3.medium  |  23.23.184.200    |
|  i-6053991b|  m1.large   |  54.221.250.189   |
```

Not sure how I would add something like this into the table

```
'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're very close. Try this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`]| [0].Value]' --output table
```

Comment: I fixed the command.  There were one too many brackets when I initially ran it.  Thanks.